# Mangle http without using a proxy (ARP Spoofing?)

Tags: android, http, tcp, proxy, arp

I'm trying to test a device that will not use proxy for http. I'd like to return a 404 status code on traffic to a certain host - normally I would utilize a proxy and mangle the responses.  In this case I'm not able to use a proxy. HTTP packet sniffing in the absense of a proxy is easy enough with wire shark or httpscoop however I can't actually mangle any of the traffic without getting in the middle.

Is it possible to easily arp spoof and modify the response? I'm guessing I'd have to either write something fairly custom to do this (which does sound like fun) OR I could find another solution like dropping all traffic to the ip using iptable rules or similar.

Edit: This is a common problem on android testing so I'm adding a tag.
I answered the question: http://mitmproxy.org/doc/certinstall/android.html
This will do it via transparent http proxying. You use a router eg iptables or pf to proxy the traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool that will handle this perfectly including ssl negotiation:

http://mitmproxy.org/doc/certinstall/android.html

It was android I'm testing but it's a general problem.